# Hide orders (table rows) in WooCommerce admin order list based on order status

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, backend, orders

I need to hide orders with a specific status in the WooCommerce admin orders list. (*wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=shop_order*).

CSS won't work as if the user only shows 20 rows, there might be a page with no results as many orders might have this status.

I tried the following function:

```php
add_action('wc_order_statuses', 'my_statuses');

function my_statuses($order_statuses) {

    unset($order_statuses['wc-my_status']);
    return $order_statuses;
}
```

...but that made conflict with my function (below) on the **Thank you page** which no longer changed the order status to my custom status, probably because the function mentioned above removes it.

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'woocommerce_thankyou_change_order_status', 10, 1 );
function woocommerce_thankyou_change_order_status( $order_id ){

    if( // my custom code ) {
        $order->update_status( 'my_status' );
      }
}
```

---

Is there no easy way to hide orders with *my_status* from the order list in WooCommerce admin panel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To hide row(s) containing a specific order status, in WooCommerce admin order list. You can use the `parse_query` action hook.

So you get:

```php
function action_parse_query( $query ) { 
    global $pagenow;
    
    // Your order status to hide, must start with 'wc-'
    $hide_order_status = 'wc-completed';

    // Initialize
    $query_vars = &$query->query_vars;
    
    // Only on WooCommerce admin order list
    if ( $pagenow == 'edit.php' && $query_vars['post_type'] == 'shop_order' ) {
        // Finds whether a variable is an array
        if ( is_array( $query_vars['post_status'] ) ) {  
            // Searches the array for a given value and returns the first corresponding key if successful
            if ( ( $key = array_search( $hide_order_status, $query_vars['post_status'] ) ) !== false ) {
                unset( $query_vars['post_status'][$key] );
            }
        }
    }

}
add_action( 'parse_query', 'action_parse_query', 10, 1 );
```